# Lightning component - display an image stored in files

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to display an image stored in the files of my org in alightning component. 
For now I just want to display an image, with its Id, not dynamically.

I tried this in my component:

```
<img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0696E000000AT3BQAW'}" alt="" />
```

but the image is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ContentVersion` (prefix 068), not the `ContentDocument` (069), then you can display it like this:

```
<img src="{!'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/' + v.contentVersion.Id}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `{!''}` since you are refering to an absolute path.

`<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0696E000000AT3BQAW" alt="" />`

Comment: this syntax doesn't work either...

Comment: I just tested it, for me it worked.

Do you get the image displayed when you open the following link?
https://`namespace`/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0696E000000AT3BQAW

Comment: no when I click the link I got an error. I'm in lightning experience but when I click the link I'm redirected to classic

Comment: `servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=*Id*` points to an image in _Documents_ which is currently only accessible via Classic. 
When you set the _namespace_ in the aboves link correctly you should be able to see the image. Otherwise it doesn't exist (afaik). Make sure you got the correct Id of the image.

Comment: my image exist in the files of lightning experience, not in classic... Can I access it from an url ?

Comment: Sorry, thought you are in _Documents_ cause of the given URL. 
Yes, you can. Open _Files_, select your file and preview it. Right click and copy image location. Paste the saved URL in a new tab. 
It should look something like this:
`https://*namespace*.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Jpg&versionId=*ID*`
Take a look at Aiden's answer. He uses a shortend version of the link.